# How to convert my bitcoins to another currency

Tags: exchanges, payment, retail

I'm a merchant, and I'm looking for a complementary method of payment.

How can I exchange bitcoins for my local currency?

Comment: David has already edited out the offending part, but - bitcoins are real money, and you'll receive less sympathy if you imply that they're not.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoins can be sold for other currencies at Bitcoin exchanges and exchange services. There are many exchanges all over the world (listed [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Currency_exchanges)), but the largest exchange with the greatest depth is [Mt. Gox](https://mtgox.com).

You can also use a merchant services provider such as [Bit-Pay](https://bit-pay.com/) which will automatically handle for you both receiving Bitcoin payments and immediately converting them to other currencies.